# Using multiple derived tables to hit indices

Tags: sql, ignite

For context, I'm using Apache Ignite.
I have a table that is growing pretty fast, much faster than most others. Importantly, it is joined in several other queries. We're starting to get slow query exceptions when this table is involved.

Using EXPLAIN I see that the index isn't being used in many of the queries we have. It looks like the clauses may be too complex or some other aspect of the query is preventing its use.

One of the ideas I'm experimenting with us using an `INNER JOIN` on derived tables created from sub-queries. A representative example is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE T0 (a: varchar, b: varchar, c:varchar, d: varchar, e: varchar, f: varchar)
```

In the existing impl. we have 3 indices on combinations of the columns and one that includes all except 1 column (4 indices total).

A current query looks like this:

```sql
  SELECT a,b FROM T0 t0 WHERE
  (f = 123 AND (a = 'abc' OR a = 'def')) AND
  (f = 456 AND (b = 'ghi' OR c = 'jkl')) AND
  (
    (f = 567 AND (d = 'mno' OR e = 'pqr')) OR
    (f = 789 AND (a = 'abc' OR b = 'def'))
  )
```

There are 6 top level `AND`s in one of the current queries. There is an index on `f,a`, `f,b,c`, `f,d,e` and `f,a,b` but none of these are used according to the explain output.

My idea is to rewrite the above query with derived tables like this:

```sql
  SELECT a,b FROM T0 t0 
  INNER JOIN (SELECT a,b FROM T0 WHERE f = 123 AND (a = 'abc' OR a = 'def')) t1 ON t0.a = t1.a AND t0.b = t1.b
  INNER JOIN (SELECT a,b FROM T0 WHERE f = 456 AND (b = 'ghi' OR c = 'jkl')) t2 ON t0.a = t2.a AND t0.b = t2.b
  INNER JOIN (SELECT a,b FROM T0 WHERE (f = 567 AND (d = 'mno' OR e = 'pqr')) OR (f = 789 AND (a = 'abc' OR b = 'def'))) t3 ON t0.a = t3.a AND t0.b = t3.b
WHERE ...some stuff that may not hit the indices
```

The idea is that each sub-query will hit a specific index e.g. `f,a` and in the end being an `INNER JOIN` leads to a much smaller set on which the outter `t0` can have other arbitrary clauses.

What is interesting is that Ignite uses the index that includes all the columns to match the sub-queries (not the smaller, focused indices). So it appears as if this will have the desired effect but I will only need one index with all the columns as we currently have.

The outter result set (one not being joined) is still ending up as a scan but since the `INNER JOIN` is hitting the index now I'm expecting a significant difference. (It's not easy to test outside of production at the moment. Currently getting some public data to recreate).

My questions are, before I commit to going this route:

1. Is this an anti-pattern of sorts? Having had a look around I can't find many examples of others doing this
2. Is my reasoning about the INNER JOIN on the derived tables sound?
3. Why is the original parenthesised WHERE clauses too complex (seemingly) for ignite to think the index would be more optimal than a scan?
4. Are there any pitfalls to be aware of with this approach?
5. Are the number of JOINs an issue (in one case I can see we'd need to do this 8 times on the same table)
6. If I'm off here or there are better solutions, can you suggest any?

Comment: `(f = 123 AND (..)) AND (f = 456 AND (..))`  it is always false to me.

Comment: You're right, in trying to simplify but still be representative I overlooked that fact, inside the outermost parens is actually an OR in all of these cases